# Sitecore 9.3 Federated Authentication - After Authentication Sitecore roles are not getting processed for the logged in user

Tags: federated-authentication

We have implemented federated authentication in Sitecore 9.3 version. We are able to authenticate with azure AD account successfully, But after authentication Sitecore role is not getting assigned to the logged in user.

We have given config settings as per the Sitecore documentation. The expectation is after successful login, the logged in user to be assigned with a Sitecore Role (admin/author role).

The procedure/settings we followed is –

1. Created a App registration
2. Updated the Manifest(changed groupmembershipclaims value to “SecurityGroup”
3. Config entry of group object ID (the group object ID where ADuser is part of).

Kindly share your idea which can give a solution to the above problem. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: There is probably something wrong with the configuration, so we might need to see that to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing couple of config changes and some other stuff, Finally adding a optional claim with the name "groups" solved the issue. After doing this change identity server is able to resolve the claims as per the transformation config settings.
The reference to create optional claim is as per below blog.
[Please check this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims)

Comment: Hello, could you please let me know the exact steps you did to resolve this issue? I am also facing the same issue. Please elaborate your answer. At least provide the config you used for transformation.